# Converting the NSData returned from an HTTP request in Swift to a String

Tags: xcode, string, swift, nsstring, nsdata

I have some code that makes an HTTP request, then calls a function with the data, response, and error results. This function then tries to call a function, `handler`, that takes a Swift `String` as its sole argument. I have tried to convert the `NSData` object (`data`) returned from the HTTP request to an `NSString`, and then from there to a Swift `String`, but XCode gives an error saying **'(String) -> $T2' is not identical to 'String'** when I try to call my function (`handler`) on that `String` (`res`).

```
    let res: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    handler(res)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Comment: what is the definition of handler function?

Comment: The function with this code has the signature  `func do_request(url: String, data: string?, handler: (String)) {`, so the handler function could be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You syntax for the closure is wrong. 
 Try changing `handler: (String)` to `handler: (String) -> ()`

```
func do_request(url: String, data: String?, handler: (String) -> ()) {
    // Your code
    if let res: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    {
         handler(res)
    } 
}
```

Read this for more information : https://www.codefellows.org/blog/writing-completion-blocks-with-closures-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

`NSString` can be type casted to a Swift `String`, it’s even done automatically for you. So the following should be enough in your case:

```
if let res = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    handler(res)
} else {
    // handle that the data wasn’t convertible to a string.
}
```

(I added the `if let` part as it’s generally a bad idea to force-unwrap optionals.)

---

However the reason you’re getting the error however is because you’re defining the `res` constant to be of type `String`. Then you try to initialize it with an `NSString` object which the type system won’t like.

Comment: I get the error on the line where I call `handler(res)`. The first line gives no errors regardless of whether I cast it to a String with `as String`, but the second line has that error regardless as well. In other words, it still gives almost exactly the same error if I try that.